# Hide Columns with Condition VBA

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I am trying to show columns with "Register" on the certain cell,
and hide the others without "Register".

Columns 6 to 58 are hidden first

I used the below code, and got part of the result.

```
Sub Info_Register()

Dim s As Integer

For s = 6 To 58
   If Cells(13, s).Value = "Register" Then
   Columns(s).Hidden = False
   End If
Next s

End Sub
```

Why I say part of the result, because I always get the Error Type Mismatch on the below part of the code.

```
If Cells(13, s).Value = "Register" Then
```

Not sure what type is correct, need help to use the correct type.

Sample Data:

```
State             AL            HI                 CA                  NY
Status            Register      Don't register     Incomplete Data     Register
Name              Person A      Person B           Person C            Person D
Contact Number    1234567       6789043            6836281             4267889
Email Address     a@xyz.com     b@xyz.com          c@xyz.com           d@xyz.com
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly without any errors. If your goal is to just hide the columns with no "Register" string then I would do it like this: `If Cells(13, s).Value <> "Register" Then
    Columns(s).Hidden = True
   End If`

Comment: Can you share your file? an image or something? To see if I can help you with your error.

Comment: The file is kind of large, but I could place some sample data

Comment: Have you tried the code I shared with you? I think you shouldn't have problems with that one.

Comment: I have tried the code, but I still get the type mismatch error.

Comment: What if you use variant instead of integer? try it. This is extrange I don't get any error using the same code. If you want send me a piece of your file to my email to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables has a different type, for example integer, and you are testing the variable with a string, that is when you would receive the mismatch error.

On the Menu, at the top of the Window, click on Debug, and Use the Step Into button. You could also use a breakpoint, if you know where the error occurs use the Locals window to know for sure which variable, is the one with the error.

Comment: Ho do you use the Locals window?

Comment: When you use Step Into or create a breakpoint, and then run  Step Into or to the breakpoint, the locals window would open at the bottom to show the variables and their values at that point.